# If cell A1 is certain value then B1 is random between two values

Tags: excel, vba, random

I want to assign a random number between 2 values if a cell is a certain value, using VBA. I have 40 randomly generated numbers between 1 and 12, and then I want to assign to each of those 40 numbers a random number between two values, but these two values are dependent on whether the number is 1,2,3,....,12. My code looks like this now but the numbers that come out are not always between the limits that I give. What is wrong?

```
Sub measurepoints()


Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer


For i = 2 To 41
     Cells(i, 1).Value = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,12)"
Next i

For j = 2 To 41

If Cells(j, 1).Value = 1 Then
    Cells(j, 2).Value = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,2)"

ElseIf Cells(j, 1).Value = 2 Then
    Cells(j, 2).Value = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,2)"

ElseIf Cells(j, 1).Value = 3 Then
    Cells(j, 2).Value = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,8)"

ElseIf Cells(j, 1).Value = 4 Then
    Cells(j, 2).Value = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,8)"

ElseIf Cells(j, 1).Value = 5 Then
    Cells(j, 2).Value = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,8)"

ElseIf Cells(j, 1).Value = 6 Then
    Cells(j, 2).Value = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,8)"

ElseIf Cells(j, 1).Value = 7 Then
    Cells(j, 2).Value = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,4)"

ElseIf Cells(j, 1).Value = 8 Then
    Cells(j, 2).Value = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,2)"

ElseIf Cells(j, 1).Value = 8 Then
    Cells(j, 2).Value = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,8)"

ElseIf Cells(j, 1).Value = 10 Then
    Cells(j, 2).Value = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,10)"

ElseIf Cells(j, 1).Value = 11 Then
    Cells(j, 2).Value = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,4)"

ElseIf Cells(j, 1).Value = 12 Then
    Cells(j, 2).Value = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,8)"



  End If


Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a cell that has numbers outside the range?  Perhaps instead of `Value` you just need to do `...Formula = "Randbetween(#, #)"`?  At least that way, you can see if Excel is somehow changing your formula before assigning the value.

Comment: No need for VBA, `=RANDBETWEEN(1,INDEX({2,2,8,8,8,8,4,2,8,10,4,8},A1))` should do what you want

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thank you. Is there also an option that I can refresh the values in column A each time so that I get a new set of random numbers?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thanks, is it also possible to remove the duplicates each time again? So that sometimes I'll end up with more combinations than the other time depending on how many duplicates I have.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment and that may be a new question entirely

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo:

```
ElseIf Cells(j, 1).Value = 8 Then
    Cells(j, 2).Value = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,2)"

ElseIf Cells(j, 1).Value = 8 Then
    Cells(j, 2).Value = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,8)"
```

Comment: Thanks, noticed that later. Still had the same problem with assigning values that are out of range. But the answer of cybernetic.nomad worked out!

Answer (score 0):

No need for VBA:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,INDEX({2,2,8,8,8,8,4,2,8,10,4,8},A1))
```

should do what you want

To recalculate all function in a sheet, press `F9`.